# Adding icon with each row of menu in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

i'm new to android and i'm trying to add icon in each row of menu in Navigation Drawer using

**Adapter Class:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.ash.light.R;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import model.NavDrawerItem;


public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<NavDrawerItem> data= Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public NavigationDrawerAdapter(Context context, List<NavDrawerItem> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    public void delete(int position){
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_row_drawer, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
        NavDrawerItem current=data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
        holder.icon.setImageResource(current.getIcon());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            title=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            icon=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);
        }
    }


}
```

and **with model:**

```
public class NavDrawerItem {

    private boolean shownotify;
    private String title;
    private int icon;

    public NavDrawerItem(){

    }

    public NavDrawerItem(boolean shownotify, String title, int icon){
        this.shownotify=shownotify;
        this.title=title;
        this.icon=icon;
    }

    public boolean isShowNotify(){
        return shownotify;
    }

    public void setShowNotify(boolean shownotify){
        this.shownotify=shownotify;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title=title;
    }

    public int getIcon(){
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon){
        this.icon=icon;
    }
}
```

**using FragmentDrawer class:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import adapter.NavigationDrawerAdapter;
import model.NavDrawerItem;



public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

    private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
    private View containerView;
    private static String[] titles=null;
    private static int[] icons;
    private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;

  //  private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;



    public FragmentDrawer() {

    }

    public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener){
        this.drawerListener=listener;
    }

    public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData(){
        List<NavDrawerItem> data=new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
            NavDrawerItem navItem=new NavDrawerItem();
            navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
            navItem.setIcon(icons[i]);
            data.add(navItem);
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        titles=getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
        icons=getActivity().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerlist);

        adapter=new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position){
                drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position){

            }
        }));
        return layout;
    }



    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar){
        containerView=getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout=drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideoffset){
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideoffset);
                toolbar.setAlpha(1-(slideoffset/2));
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
    }


    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{
        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener){
            this.clickListener=clickListener;
            gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e){
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e){
                    View child=recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if(child!=null && clickListener!=null){
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e){
            View child=rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if(child!=null && clickListener!=null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e){

        }
    }

    public interface FragmentDrawerListener{
        public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
    }

}
```

**and MainActivity:**

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private Toolbar mtoolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mtoolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment=(FragmentDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_nav_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_nav_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mtoolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        displayView(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position){

        displayView(position);

    }


    private void displayView(int position){
        Fragment fragment=null;
        String title=getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment=new HomeFragment();
                title="Home";
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment=new AmcFragment();
                title="Amc Wise";
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment=new AssetFragment();
                title="Asset Class";
                break;

            case 3:
                fragment=new FolioFragment();
                title="Folio Based Report";
                break;

            case 4:
                fragment=new FdFragment();
                title="FD Wise";
                break;

            case 5:
                fragment=new NewsFragment();
                title="News and Updates";
                break;

            case 6:
                fragment=new CalculatorFragment();
                title="Financial Calculator";
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }

        if(fragment!=null){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.body_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

        }
    }
}
```

i not getting icon with menu items, rest everything is working fine. i know there are various other methods to get the icons with navigation bar menu, but
i want to get icons using these classes only (if possible),with minor editing.
Please help me out..